# Wordpress install - problems in getting to Administrative Panels

Tags: wordpress, installation

I have been struggling to get my initial install to work. All seemingly went well with the instal. I am sure it must be a very basic setting I have wrong.

When trying the Wordpress dashboard link to CiviCRM panel, I got a [base_dir problem](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/problem-with-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect) where I applied the recommended "fix" of adding a line to CiviCRM setting to force directory to my base wordpress instal. This progressed me a little further.

After that, now receiving ...
Fatal error: Uncaught CiviCRM_API3_Exception: [unknown error: DB Error: unknown error thrown in /home/…/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php on line 45

Thinking of abandoning CiviCRM as a Wordpress option for my needs. The install seems to be problematic.

However, if anyone is willing and has the time to work with me to resolve the issues, I am really keen to use the product and willing to give it a good crack :)

Cheers,
Garry

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace on the error? It's impossible to know what's triggering this otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Christian - I shall research to see how to turn this option on

Comment: @ChristianWach I added some [database entries](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60283321/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-17%20at%2010.12.18%20AM.png)  that should have enabled backtrace, but there is nothing additional appearing on the page or in the log.

Comment: Trying another clean install.

Comment: Ok - [same result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60283321/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-15%20at%205.21.18%20PM.png) (Isn't that the definition of insanity?) Back to original message, which did also occur after plugin activation, and PRIOR to the Install

Comment: Hi Garry, that last screenshot does help - it seems that CiviCRM can't find a WordPress file that it's looking for in order to validate that WordPress is present. Have you got a value for `CIVICRM_CMSDIR` in civicrm.settings.php?

Comment: Hi Christian, The virgin install does not have that setting in the settings file. As  mentioned above, when I DO add such a setting, I then get a different error ... Fatal error: Uncaught CiviCRM_API3_Exception: [unknown error: DB Error: unknown error thrown in /home/…/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php on line 45

Comment: I have tried having the database as both standalone, and as part of the CMS database - same result in both cases.