# Cron issue with shared hosting

Tags: cron-job, cron

CiviCRM 4.6.7

I get an error with this command: 
wget -O - -q -t 1 'http://www.website.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=user&pass=password&key=site-key'

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Function
>   "is_admin()" is missing, even though WordPress is the user framework.'
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php:258

Thanks for helping.

Edit:

With CLI PHP I get this error:

This what I get with CLI PHP:

Sorry. A non-recoverable error has occurred.
Could not find the install directory for WordPress

```
#0 /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php(343): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find the install directory for WordPress")
#1 /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(1500): CRM_Utils_System_WordPress->loadBootStrap((Array:0), FALSE, FALSE, "/var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/")
#2 /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php(251): CRM_Utils_System::loadBootStrap((Array:0), FALSE, FALSE, "/var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/")
#3 /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php(72): civicrm_cli->_bootstrap()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php(31): civicrm_cli->initialize()
#5 {main}
```

Comment: Did you try using CLI PHP?

Comment: I am having this same issue. I have used the provided code to define the Wordpress install directory, but I am still unable to run the Cron. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. The path to the wordpress directory was wrong, don't know why. I have changed hosting during the week.

I had to add this line in civicrm.settings.php:

```
define('CIVICRM_CMSDIR','/var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs');
```

This issue helped me: [Problem with open_basedir restriction in effect](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/problem-with-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect)